# Retrofit MultipartBody.Part Not Sendig Data

Tags: android, laravel, retrofit

I have tested the api with postman it is working fine.So no issue from API end. I am sending multiple params with files. I have also logging enabled in retrofit via OkHttpClient Interceptor. In logging also data is sent is showing. **But validator of api is throwing error 'title' field is required.**

```
 @Multipart
@PUT("song/{id}")
Single<JsonObject> updateSong(@Path("id") int song_id,@Part MultipartBody.Part title, @Part MultipartBody.Part  cat_id, @Part MultipartBody.Part  playlist_id,
                              @Part MultipartBody.Part audio_file, @Part MultipartBody.Part thumbnail_file);
```

Here is code of API[Laravel PHP]:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'audio_file' =>'mimes:application/octet-stream|nullable,
        audio/mpeg,mpga,mp3,wav',
        'thumbnail_file' => 'mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048|nullable',
        'title' => 'required',

    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) { 
        return response()->json(['status'=>false,'data'=>null,'message'=>$validator->errors()]); 
    }else{
        return response()->json(['status'=>true,'data'=>null,'message'=>null]); 

    }
```

Here is the log of retrofit:

[image]

This way I am sending data:

```
  public Single<JsonObject> updateSong(int song_id,String title, int cat_id,int playlist_id, MultipartBody.Part audio_file, MultipartBody.Part thumbnail_file){
    MultipartBody.Part titleBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("title", title);

    MultipartBody.Part songCatIdBody;
    MultipartBody.Part playlistIdBody;
    if (cat_id>0){
        songCatIdBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("song_category_id", String.valueOf(cat_id));
    }else {
        songCatIdBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("song_category_id", null);

    }
    if (playlist_id>0){
        playlistIdBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("playlist_id", String.valueOf(playlist_id));
    }else {
        playlistIdBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("playlist_id", null);

    }

    return songAPI.updateSong(song_id,titleBody,songCatIdBody,playlistIdBody,audio_file,thumbnail_file);
}
```

**Update:**

The problem is solved if I make the API route to POST. I think PUT request not supported by retrofit for sending multipart data.

Comment: you are using @Path("id") change it to @Part

Comment: I have tried that also not worked..

Comment: @Part is used to send body.. where @Path is used to concatenate API URL with some data..here is id of the song...check URL `song/{id}`...

Answer (score 0):

```
private void uploadFile(Uri fileUri) {  
// create upload service client
FileUploadService service =
        ServiceGenerator.createService(FileUploadService.class);

// https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java
// use the FileUtils to get the actual file by uri
File file = FileUtils.getFile(this, fileUri);

// create RequestBody instance from file
RequestBody requestFile =
        RequestBody.create(
                     MediaType.parse(getContentResolver().getType(fileUri)),
                     file
         );

// MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
MultipartBody.Part body =
        MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", file.getName(), requestFile);

// add another part within the multipart request
String descriptionString = "hello, this is description speaking";
RequestBody description =
        RequestBody.create(
                okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, descriptionString);

// finally, execute the request
Call<ResponseBody> call = service.upload(description, body);
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call,
                           Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        Log.v("Upload", "success");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("Upload error:", t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

}

Comment: please explain your answer...its a copy-paste code .. I have seen it much time..